# WSO2ESB - Spring mediator

Tags: spring, web-services, wso2, esb, mediator

I have problem with creating Spring Mediator who have inside Web Service Client. This mediator is crashed when try initializing Web Service object.

Error is:

> "Uncaught exception
>   {org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool}
>   javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder$ConfigurationError: Provider
>   org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl not found".

I tried to add jars like "cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws" but without result. (To 'WSO2_HOME\repository\components\lib')

WSO2ESB version is 4.8.1.

Could you please explain me how to solve this.

Comment: Did you check whether org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl  class is available in the Jars you added?

Answer (score 0):

If the jars are OSGi bundles, you should put them into

```
 <WSO2_HOME>\repository\components\dropins\
```